# create icon with css instead of using an image

Tags: css

I have this icon which is used in the menu of a large website running Bootstrap 3.7.

Icon: [image: Nav icon]

I would like to see if I can recreate it with css only. I think I'm close but I would like the red arrow to fill the gray square from top to bottom.

```
ul>li>a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 7px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #901a1e;
  content: "\e258";
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Anyone who can make it look even more identical?

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/k318cbpf/).

Comment: Question: Is there a reason you're using a Glyphicons symbol instead of simply using the `>` greater-than character (`\3E`)?

Comment: Yeah, '>' seems to be too slim and not quite the right angle...

Comment: Fair enough. 

Answer (score 0):

According to you your before icon should be in red color and which is within grey square right.

So to get grey square you have to gice background color grey to before, you can see the code in below:

```
`ul>li>a::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 0 1px 0 0;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-size: 7px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 10px;
  color: #901a1e;
  content: "\e258";
  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  Background-color:grey;
}`
```

or

you can also see in below link

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/k318cbpf/3/)